# Extracting unique caller information in java

Tags: java, reflection

What I want to do is implement some basic security by checking not only what class has called a particular method, but also, which instance of that class.

I tried

> `StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();`

but that obviously only gives me the class name.  The problem with allowing/requiring the callers to send self, or personal IDs is that all the callers are required to have access to the details of all the others.  Can anyone help?

EDIT: More information:

So we have a server which makes connections with several agents.  The agents send packets of information which include the name they CLAIM to have.  There is a special agent which decides whether or not people should be able to lie about this in each particular case.

The agents make connections to instances of an Agent class on the server, but there is also a possibility that some agents will run natively.  The reason I'm interested in this approach is that I will need that technique later (extract the specific instance that called a given method)

I hope this is better, and sorry for not putting enough info before :/

Comment: As bmargulies said, you won't be able to secure anything this way.  If you tell us more about what you're doing and why you're trying to do it, perhaps we can help you come up with another approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This whole line of attack can't possible secure anything. If users can control the code that runs, they can just run a codegen library and edit your code. If users can't control the code, then this is all unnecessary.

If you can't resist this urge, one approach is to wrap everything in Proxies that communicate the information you need.

By Proxy, I mean `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. That is, wrap every one of these objects in a proxy. The proxy's job would be to store away `this` on a stack of your own that the callees could consult.

This is essentially AOP (aspect oriented programming) reinvented, so you might want to read about that. Look at the Spring framework.

Comment: Ok so I think I didn't give enough info.  The whole structure is on a server and the agents are already proxies.  The problem is that the proxy sends a packet which has some data in it.  The server just needs to add a tag to it to say which proxy it's from.

Answer (score 1):

You are not securing anything like this.

I think for such problems just check that all contributing code comes from signed jars.

Comment: I just want to verify identity. People can lie all they like as long as we know which lies were told by the same person.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Capability-based security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security). Instead of knowing which client is doing what, you should give each client separate capability objects (essentially proxy objects with different privileges).